# Mongoose updateMany with an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, insert-update

i am currently having an issue with mongoose.

I am developing a network mapper app (yes I know, Nmap exists) and I am having this issue to save or update the hosts in the database.

Currently, I have what I need working but I feel like it's not the right solution (it's for a personal project, so I want to do it as properly as I can).

My solution is the following:

```
public async create(createHost: CreateHostDto) {
    return this.hostModel.findOneAndUpdate({ user_id: createHost.user_id, network_id: 
        createHost.network_id, address: createHost.address }, createHost, { upsert: true, new: true })
}

public async createMany(createHosts: CreateHostDto[]) {

    const returnHosts = [];
    for (const host of createHosts) {
        const dbHost = await this.create(host);
        returnHosts.push(dbHost);
    }
    return returnHosts;
}
```

All I want is that when I call the endpoint to create my hosts, it checks for the **user_id**, **network_id**, and **address** fields to match any existing document within the database.
If there's a matched document, it should update it, otherwise, it should create it.

Thank you in advance.